# how to loop through nested child nodes

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I need help writing a for loop for the firebase nested child elements. I have provided the code below.Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
      Item features
           -sdsmkdffd
              model:1234
              left 
                -sjjkjsd9999999
                     left:3456

              right
                 -sjkjksdjkjkj
                      right:0990
```

code listing,

```
# I dont have a problem with this part of the looping
usernames = database.child("Items").child('details').get()
for user in usernames.each():
    userid = user.key()
    dtls = database.child("Items").child('details').child(userid).child('iname').get().val()       
        if dtls == name:
        dtls1 = database.child("Items").child('details').child(userid).child('idesc').get().val()
        dtls2 = database.child("Items").child('details').child(userid).child('imodel').get().val()
       usernames = database.child("Item_features").get()
       for user in usernames.each():
       userid = user.key()
       dtls55 =  database.child("Item_features").child(userid).child('model').get().val()
       if dtls55 == dtls2:
          #here I want to loop through the nested child nodes of 
          #'left'
```

Comment: your code is badly formatted, its hard to workout what is in a loop & what is not

Comment: i m so sorry , i tried my best

Comment: OK have edited your code formatting, it'll show up after its been reviewed. Check it to see if I have got the indentation correct

Comment: I corrected the indentation again . Can you give me a solution now please

Comment: yes I'd noticed, looks worse than before I'm afraid